# Blender Opens With Only Gray Screen

Tags: modeling

So I'm using Blender, and then all of a sudden I zoom out and there's nothing but a gray screen. I've tried hitting the / . , keys but . and , only open up orientation menus and / will only zoom on one object (not the whole render)

Shown Here:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click “n” it will open the 3D view properties tab, you can adjust the “start” and “end” value. And if you change the end value to something big like “10^10”, you should be able to see everything and you might also need to select an active object and click “.” again.